# Stripping punctuation from a list of lists of words

Tags: python

I wish to remove all punctuations from a list of list of words like this while keeping the format the same:
The sentence is: I am going home. I will see, if I can do that! I will see?

So this is how my dataset looks like:

```
[[u'i', u'am', u'going', u'home.', u'i', u'will', u'see,', u'if', u'i', u'can', u'do', u'that!', u'i', u'will', u'see?']]
```

How can I get rid of the punctuation? String methods don't work since the data is in a list of list format.

This is what I have tried:

```
punc=res
punc=[''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in punc]
print(punc)
```

Where res is my dataset in the above mentioned format. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your snippet is not working is because you have a list inside a list. Your code only handles a flat list. See below:

```
[[u'i', u'am', u'going', u'home.', u'i', u'will', u'see,', u'if', u'i', u'can', u'do', u'that!', u'i', u'will', u'see?']]
```

If you remove the extra brackets, your code will work:

```
>>> punc = [u'i', u'am', u'going', u'home.', u'i', u'will', u'see,', u'if', u'i', u'can', u'do', u'that!', u'i', u'will', u'see?']
>>> print [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in punc]
[u'i', u'am', u'going', u'home', u'i', u'will', u'see', u'if', u'i', u'can', u'do', u'that', u'i', u'will', u'see']
```

---

You can simplify that code a little bit by calling [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

```
>>> [x.strip(string.punctuation) for x in punc]
[u'i',
 u'am',
 u'going',
 u'home',
 u'i',
 u'will',
 u'see',
 u'if',
 u'i',
 u'can',
 u'do',
 u'that',
 u'i',
 u'will',
 u'see']
```

If you need to handle lists inside lists (like in your example), just add another loop. This works with your original snippet as well.

```
>>> [[x.strip(string.punctuation) for x in y] for y in punc]
[[u'i',
  u'am',
  u'going',
  u'home',
  u'i',
  u'will',
  u'see',
  u'if',
  u'i',
  u'can',
  u'do',
  u'that',
  u'i',
  u'will',
  u'see']]
```

Comment: Work's perfectly now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `re.sub`

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
>>> s = [[u'i', u'am', u'going', u'home.', u'i', u'will', u'see,', u'if', u'i', u'can', u'do', u'that!', u'i', u'will', u'see?']]
>>> [re.sub(r'[' + re.escape(punctuation) + ']', '', j) for i in s for j in i]
[u'i', u'am', u'going', u'home', u'i', u'will', u'see', u'if', u'i', u'can', u'do', u'that', u'i', u'will', u'see']
```